# How to I resolve this error? Field never assigned and will always have null value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created 4 c# scripts. When I run my 2d unity game I see this warning in my console.

> "Assets\Scripts\GameHandler.cs(7,34): warning CS0649: Field
>   'GameHandler.car' is never assigned to, and will always have its
>   default value null"

I am creating a game similar to snake, using c# scripts in unity 2d. Never used unity before or c#, this is my first project. So far its going well, However, i keep getting this warning which is causing my game to crash. 
I've attached 2 of my scripts the first gamehandler is where this issue is and I think its referring to the class `Car` which i attached below. It's a lot of code so I do apologise, I just have no clue.

```
public class GameHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Car car;

    private LevelGrid levelGrid;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("GameHandler.Start");

        //GameObject carHeadGameObject = new GameObject();
        //SpriteRenderer carSpriteRenderer = carHeadGameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        //carSpriteRenderer.sprite = GameAssets.instance.carHeadSprite;

        levelGrid = new LevelGrid(20,20); //width,height of grid

        car.Setup(levelGrid);
        levelGrid.Setup(car);
    }


    }
--------------------------------------
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Car : MonoBehaviour
{
    private enum Direction
    {
        Left,
        Right,
        Up,
        Down
    }

    private enum State
    {
        Alive,
        Dead
    }

    private State state;
    private Vector2Int gridPosition; //uses ints instead of floats useful for grid positiioning
    private float gridMoveTimer; //time remaining until next movement
    private float gridMoveTimerMax; // time between moves

    private Direction gridMoveDirection;

    private LevelGrid levelGrid;
    private int carsize;
    private List<CarMovePosition> carMovePositionList;
    private List<Carsize> carSizeList;

    public void Setup(LevelGrid levelGrid) {
        this.levelGrid = levelGrid;
    }

    private void Awake() {
        gridPosition = new Vector2Int(10,10); //initalise grid position into middle of grid 
        gridMoveTimerMax = .2f; //car to move along grid every 1/2 second
        gridMoveTimer = gridMoveTimerMax; //0f
        gridMoveDirection = Direction.Right; // default move right

        carMovePositionList = new List<CarMovePosition>();
        carsize = 0;
        carSizeList = new List<Carsize>();

        state = State.Alive;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case State.Alive:
            HandleInput(); // checks for keyboard input
            HandleGridMovement();
                break;
            case State.Dead:
                break;
        }



    }


    private void HandleInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            if (gridMoveDirection != Direction.Down)
            { // can only go up if not going down
                gridMoveDirection = Direction.Up;
            }
        }
        //return true on up arrow press

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            if (gridMoveDirection != Direction.Up)
            {
                gridMoveDirection = Direction.Down;

            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            if (gridMoveDirection != Direction.Right)
            {
                gridMoveDirection = Direction.Left;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            if (gridMoveDirection != Direction.Left)
            {
                gridMoveDirection = Direction.Right;
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleGridMovement()
    {
        gridMoveTimer += Time.deltaTime; // amount of time left since last update
        if (gridMoveTimer >= gridMoveTimerMax)//if true then 1 sec since last move
        {
            gridMoveTimer -= gridMoveTimerMax;

            CarMovePosition previousCarMovePosition = null;

            if (carMovePositionList.Count > 0){
                previousCarMovePosition = carMovePositionList[0];
            }

            CarMovePosition carMovePosition = new CarMovePosition(previousCarMovePosition, gridPosition, gridMoveDirection);
            carMovePositionList.Insert(0, carMovePosition);

            Vector2Int gridMoveDirectionVector;
            switch (gridMoveDirection) {
                default:
                case Direction.Right: gridMoveDirectionVector = new Vector2Int(+1, 0);break;
                case Direction.Left: gridMoveDirectionVector = new Vector2Int(-1, 0); break;
                case Direction.Up: gridMoveDirectionVector = new Vector2Int(0, +1); break;
                case Direction.Down: gridMoveDirectionVector = new Vector2Int(0, -1); break;
            }
            gridPosition += gridMoveDirectionVector;

            bool cargotfuel = levelGrid.Trycarfuel(gridPosition);
            if (cargotfuel)
            {
                carsize++;
                CreateCarSize();
            }


            if (carMovePositionList.Count >= carsize + 1)
            {
                carMovePositionList.RemoveAt(carMovePositionList.Count - 1);
            }

            foreach (Carsize carsize in carSizeList)
            {
                Vector2Int carSizeGridPosition = carsize.GetGridPosition();
                if (gridPosition == carSizeGridPosition)
                {

                    //print("Gameover");
                    state = State.Dead;
                }
            }


            transform.position = new Vector3(gridPosition.x, gridPosition.y);
            //move transform based on location of gridPosition

            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, GetAngleFromVector(gridMoveDirectionVector) - 90);
            //modify transform to face the correct way

            UpdateCarSize();

        }
    }


    private void CreateCarSize()
    {
        carSizeList.Add(new Carsize(carSizeList.Count));
    }

    private void UpdateCarSize(){
        for (int i = 0; i < carSizeList.Count; i++) {
            carSizeList[i].SetCarMovePosition(carMovePositionList[i]);
            //carSizeList[i].SetGridPosition(carMovePositionList[i].GetGridPosition());
        }
    }

    private float GetAngleFromVector(Vector2Int dir)
    {
        float n = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        if (n < 0) n += 360;
        return n;
    }

    public Vector2Int GetGridPosition()
    {
        return gridPosition;
    }

    //returns car list of positions full with body
    public List<Vector2Int> Getcargridpositionlist(){
        List<Vector2Int> gridPositionList = new List<Vector2Int>() { gridPosition };
        foreach (CarMovePosition carMovePosition in carMovePositionList)
        {
            gridPositionList.Add(carMovePosition.GetGridPosition());
        }
        return gridPositionList;
    }

    private class Carsize{

        private CarMovePosition carMovePosition;
        private Transform transform;

        public Carsize(int sizeIndex){
            GameObject carsGameObject = new GameObject("carBody", typeof(SpriteRenderer));
            carsGameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = GameAssets.instance.carsSprite;
            carsGameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = -sizeIndex;
            transform = carsGameObject.transform;
        }

        public void SetCarMovePosition(CarMovePosition carMovePosition){
            this.carMovePosition = carMovePosition;

            transform.position = new Vector3(carMovePosition.GetGridPosition().x, carMovePosition.GetGridPosition().y);

            float angle;
            switch (carMovePosition.GetDirection()){
            default:
                case Direction.Up:// going up
                    switch (carMovePosition.GetPreviousDirection()){
                        default:
                            angle = 0; break;
                        case Direction.Left: // was going left
                            angle = 0 + 45; break;
                        case Direction.Right:// was going right
                            angle = 0 - 45; break;
                    }
                    break;
                case Direction.Down:
                    switch (carMovePosition.GetPreviousDirection()){
                        default:
                            angle = 180; break;
                        case Direction.Left:
                            angle = 180 + 45; break;
                        case Direction.Right:
                            angle = 180 - 45; break;
                    }
                    break;
                case Direction.Left:
                    switch (carMovePosition.GetPreviousDirection()){
                        default:
                            angle = -90; break;
                        case Direction.Down:
                            angle = -45; break;
                        case Direction.Up:
                            angle = 45; break;
                    }
                    break;
                case Direction.Right: // going right
                    switch (carMovePosition.GetPreviousDirection()){
                    default:
                        angle = 90; break;
                    case Direction.Down: // previously going down
                        angle = 45; break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, angle);
        }

        public Vector2Int GetGridPosition()
        {
            return carMovePosition.GetGridPosition();
        }
    } 

    private class CarMovePosition{

        private CarMovePosition previousCarMovePosition;
        private Vector2Int gridPosition;
        private Direction direction;

        public CarMovePosition(CarMovePosition previousCarMovePosition, Vector2Int gridPosition, Direction direction){
            this.previousCarMovePosition = previousCarMovePosition;
            this.gridPosition = gridPosition;
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        public Vector2Int GetGridPosition(){
            return gridPosition;
        }

        public Direction GetDirection(){
            return direction;
        }

        public Direction GetPreviousDirection(){
            if (previousCarMovePosition == null){
                return Direction.Right;
            } else {
                return previousCarMovePosition.direction;
            }
        }

    }
    }
```

It may be the case of clicking/dragging something in unity2d itself which I had to do before. But I am so lost now.

Comment: @Sean Ah.. Unity magic. Rather than ignoring it, perhaps declaring it as `[SerializeField] private Car car = null;` would be better then - so that it doesn't give the warning? Or would that break Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning occurs because you are not initializing the object "car" and your game crashes when it tries to use this object, which has no value assigned to.

You must initialize the any object before using it in order to avoid crashes.

So, your Start() method must be like this:

```
private void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("GameHandler.Start");

    car = new Car(); // you must initialize objects before using them!

    //GameObject carHeadGameObject = new GameObject();
    //SpriteRenderer carSpriteRenderer = carHeadGameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    //carSpriteRenderer.sprite = GameAssets.instance.carHeadSprite;

    levelGrid = new LevelGrid(20,20); //width,height of grid

    car.Setup(levelGrid);
    levelGrid.Setup(car);
}
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: This is true for normal applications but not for Unity. The field is marked with the SerializeField attribute, which means you can assign the value from the inspector.

Answer (score 6):

It's telling you that

```
[SerializeField] private Car car;
```

is not initialized in code, but that's fine, because you're initializing it in the inspector. If you want to get rid of the warning, you can set it to null:

```
[SerializeField] private Car car = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to suppress the error or set a value for all of your parameters, another solution is to set it from "private" to "private protected".

```
[SerializeField] private protected Car car;
```